# Using conditional formatting based on "if" formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get a cell to highlight yellow if two things are happening. If one cell is more than 0, then the cell I need highlighted will be less than 3. If 3 or higher, then no fill.  I typed in this formula, but it is not working:

=if(D44>0,if(F44<3,Not sure what to put here, but entered 0) I then used the yellow fill.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` no `IF` needed:

```
=AND(D44>0,F44<3)
```

It will return TRUE/FALSE which is what Conditional Formatting is expecting.

Comment: This worked! I also checked "Stop if True". Thanks very much.